# Website Shortcut Icon White Background

Tags: html, header, icons, favicon, ico

Hi ive setup a Favorite icon one my site and when I try to make a shortcut on the desktop for the website it creates a icon on the shortcut that looks like this:

[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

Can anybody suggest what might be happening and what is needed to correct this issues.

Below is how i have defined the Favorite icon.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://elliotrees.co.uk/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love this site and use it for all of my websites https://realfavicongenerator.net/ It creates favicons for every device out there today and gives you the favicons and the code for the html pages

Comment: That is one easy and powerful tool. Not what I was looking for but has solved my problems and a few more things as well. This is going straight into the tool bag.

Comment: I love it. It has helped me out so much.

Comment: @Xyloman As the author of RFG, thank you gentlemen for your messages :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had tried this site out from the beginning but I took the shortcut and just included the `favicon.ico` and called it with the normal link tag. It was showing a white background. This time I took the time to through the wizard, and pasted all the code the page deliver and worked!